# Issue with MSAL 4.16.0 when using Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, kerberos-delegation

I am writing a dotnet core console app that makes use of MSAL library to generate access token. I am making use of Integrated Windows Authentication as all the constraints that are mentioned in [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication) link are satisfied by the organization I am in. This seems to work fine with MSAL 4.15.0 library version. But once I start using MSAL 4.16.0 version, I end up getting the following exception.

```
Inner Excception: MSAL.NetCore.4.16.0.0.MsalServiceException:
        ErrorCode: federated_service_returned_error
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Federated service at <URL> returned error:
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.WsTrustWebRequestManager.GetWsTrustResponseAsync(WsTrustEndpoint wsTrustEndpoint, String wsTrustRequest, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.GetWsTrustResponseAsync(UserAuthType userAuthType, String cloudAudienceUrn, WsTrustEndpoint endpoint, String username, SecureString securePassword)
        StatusCode: 401
        ResponseBody:
        Headers: Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 20:24:54 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Set-Cookie: PF=QSEPNWjNTF0s1lakkLKluT;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;SameSite=None
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<---
```

Here is the simple code that I wrote:

```
            app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithTenantId(tenant).WithAuthority(authority).Build();
            try
            {
                Task<AuthenticationResult> result = app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).WithUsername(username).ExecuteAsync();
                Console.Write(result.Result.AccessToken);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Just to further clarify, this works fine untill [MSAL 4.15.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.15.0). It starts failing from the version [MSAL 4.16.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.16.0) and above.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

For people who are facing this issue, this is a known bug and is being investigated. Check it out on [Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1988)